# Does "on its ownsome" have an apostrophe or not in the its?

Tags: apostrophe

Referring to (say) some computer code, a table, or whatever:

"It sits there and does it on its ownsome."

Should be its or it's ?

(Unrelated aside on spelling of ownsome. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ownsome I'd say ownsum is also a popular spelling, perhaps emphasizing the slang aspect.)

Comment: Using `it's` when `its` (the possessive) is required is a very annoying error, which does a very great deal to make a person seem illiterate.

Comment: There was a famous *Life in Hell* strip about just that, and I've often reference it on here.  Sadly the comic it no longer seems to be online.

Comment: Why would you even ask this? I don't get it.

Comment: There's something a bit "oxymoronic" about this question, since ***ownsome*** is sufficiently colloquial / dialectal that most people who use it in most contexts wouldn't know and/or care about "correct orthography".

Comment: Perhaps 'ownsome' is some kind of hash-up of 'lonesome'. But a *table* does it on its ownsome?

Comment: ["Its" and "it's" - how to remember?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/605/2818)  and lots of duplicates.

Comment: Asked by someone who has 11k rep on ELU I don't think this question was posted in good faith.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - that makes no sense

Comment: @WeatherVane - amazing you don't know the famous Churchill anecdote

Comment: @WeatherVane what the hell are you talking about?  I'm poor at grammar and I don't know what sort of word "ownsome" is. Is it a verb? An adjective? I have no idea about the apostrophe rule in such an unusual case.

Comment: @Fattie: Just considering the relatively low number of native Anglohones who would ever say *It does it on its ownsome* non-facetiously, I'm quite sure the proportion of those speaker who have obviously limited writing / spelling skills would be *far* higher than the percentage of "illiterates" in the native Anglophone population as a whole. That's to say, those people aren't likely to know or care whether that apostrophe should be present or not. To most of them, it'll probably be on a par with the "Greengrocer's Apostrophe".

Comment: (3) I happened to just then use the phrase (in writing, obviously, this is about the written word) and it's why I asked. As I mention I have no idea what sort of word "ownsome" is.  (4) Regarding the regionality, I wonder if it's "Southern"; lonesome, ownsome.  I can't imagine it being used facetiously; it's used in a kind of humorous, throwback, deliberately-twangy way, I think. My folks are from Scotland so maybe it's a "northern" thing IDK, but that doesn't sound right. As  I mention below if you just google, say, https://www.google.com/search?q=all+on+her+ownsome any# of songs, books etc.

Answer (score 2):

The spelling "it's" is reserved for the contraction of "it is".
The possessive of "it" is always spelled "its", without an apostrophe.

Comment: Don't get me started on `who's` where `whose` is required.

Comment: Awesome answer Jack.  It's all on its ownsum for now.

Comment: @Fattie BTW, thanks for "ownsome", which I hadn't seen before. It's in Wiktionary and Collins, at onelook.com.

Comment: Intriguing; as a first-timer hearer it makes perfect sense right?  Perhaps it's a regional thing; or maybe you have to be older.  IDK.  Now I want to know the regionality or era ...

Comment: @Fattie [Online Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ownsome) has no results for 'ownsome'.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'd suggest not using comic online "references".  It's a totally commonplace term. Simply google, say, https://www.google.com/search?q=all+on+her+ownsome for numerous books, songs, etc.  As mentioned (and, obviously) it must be regional and/or more common in certain decades.